# Why is RPBroadcastPickerView rendering a blank white screen?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-native-module, rpsystembroadcastpickerview

Ive created a native iOS module for a react-native (v0.61.5) application. all it does is return the native RPBroadcastPickerView. what i expect is the picker view to be displayed, but only a blank white screen displays in my test.

heres what the native module looks like:

```
#import <ReplayKit/ReplayKit.h>
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>

@interface BroadcastPickerManager : RCTViewManager
@end

@implementation BroadcastPickerManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(BroadcastPicker)

- (UIView *)view
{
  return [[RPSystemBroadcastPickerView alloc] init];
}

@end
```

heres what it looks like in RN

BroadcastPickerView.js:

```
import { requireNativeComponent, View } from 'react-native'

module.exports = requireNativeComponent('BroadcastPicker')
```

TestScreen.js:

```
class TestScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
       <BroadcastPickerView style={{ height: 200, width: 200, backgroundColor: 'blue'}} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Ive tried setting the frame in native code, as well as setting width/height in javascript. setting native code had no affect. setting height/width in javascript show a view in the background color i choose. not entirely sure what i expect to happen but im guessing the RPBroadcastPickerView isnt a black empty view.

React native docs on native module development found [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.61/native-components-ios) say this:

> Note: Do not attempt to set the frame or backgroundColor properties on
> the UIView instance that you expose through the -view method. React
> Native will overwrite the values set by your custom class in order to
> match your JavaScript component's layout props. If you need this
> granularity of control it might be better to wrap the UIView instance
> you want to style in another UIView and return the wrapper UIView
> instead. See Issue 2948 for more context.

Not sure if im just missing something, but nothing renders when this screen is navigated to. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a frame size to the RPSystemBroadcastPickerView:

```
- (UIView *)view
{
  return [[RPSystemBroadcastPickerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
}
```

Note that changing the `frame` property doesn't resize `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` (at least on iOS 13). Autolayout doesn't resize the view as well.

You can find a Swift example in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpsystembroadcastpickerview):

```
let broadcastPicker = RPSystemBroadcastPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, to no avail. See my edit above

Comment: Did you try to inspect the element size of both wrapper view and BroadcastPickerView, did it become correct after your edit? The `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView ` is a small round button that could be [red](https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*Cd1Ecd3XA0_aI07AKQYeEQ.png). Maybe try to change your wrapper background color because red doesn't allow to see the button.

Comment: I just did some tests that shows that changing `frame` property or using autolayout doesn't update `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView ` frame. Calling the `initWithFrame` looks like the only correct solution. I've updated the answer.